# Check Constraint in MariaDB 10.1.48 not working

Tags: mariadb

i have following table:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
    a INT, 
    b INT, 
    CONSTRAINT a_greater CHECK (a>b)
);
```

So, a must be larger than b.
When executing this insert, it should not work:

```
insert into t1(a,b) values (4,5);
```

Still, i can run the Statement.

[image: 1]

The Version of the Database: `10.1.48-MariaDB-0+deb9u2`

I know, i could achieve this with a trigger, but this is way too much effort, just to do what actually should be done by the CHECK-Constraint.

Is there a bug or could that be due to any wrong configuration?
What could cause this behaviour and how could i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MariaDB [CONSTRAINT](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/constraint/)
chapter has this statement:

> Before MariaDB 10.2.1 constraint expressions were accepted in the syntax but ignored.

Your version of MariaDB 10.1.48 is too early, so the
CONSTRAINT clause is syntactically verified but is
otherwise ignored.

You need to upgrade MariaDB, the current version is
[11.4.1](https://mariadb.org/) from February 2024.